# Font family "Poppins" not working properly on my Website when it loads

Tags: fonts, google-font-api

first I want to thank all of the great people in this site. Without the help of SO I would be so lost.

I am trying to reference the typography from google fonts. The problem is that when I push the changes the font will be displayed on the console but, it won't render on the actual website.

Here is how I am importing to the code

```html
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,700,900');
</style>
```

```css
.text{ 
    font-family: 'poppins-bold', sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 6.3rem;
    line-height: 1.333;
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Check out the website [here](https://diegozito.com) and see for yourself.

Any ways into fixing this?

Answer (score 8):

Just add

```
    <style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@700&display=swap');
</style>
```

And then inside the css

```
   *{
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding the below link in the index.html (main html file) and then you can use font-family as 'poppins'.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" />
```

(you have to wrap this using <> to make it a tag)

Answer (score 0):

```
*{font-family:Poppins,sans-serif;font-weight:700}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Poppins Bold font has a problem - the family is Poppins instead of Bold.

There is a description of the issue here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1281162#c3
[image: FontForge screenshot showing wrong Family Name]

You can fix it by renaming the font using a tool such as fontforge [image: FontForge screenshot showing correct Family Name]