# Poppins @import not working external style issue

Tags: css, import, fonts

I'm making a very simple index page and am trying to incorporate some specific fonts. My goal is to `@import` Poppins from the Google API URL and then use the `*` selector to add it to every element. My CSS is as follows:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
}
```

However, when I do this, the font stays exactly the same in the default sans-serif. Following some other posts, ([Font family "Poppins" not working properly on my Website when it loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151849/font-family-poppins-not-working-properly-on-my-website-when-it-loads)) I did this in my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wavy Section SVG</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: 'Poppins';transition: 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Text</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Which then worked perfectly, allowing the text to be Poppins not sans-serif. I know it may be a bit pedantic but I do not want internal styling. Why is my `@import` tag not working? Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace * by body

```
body {
font-family: 'Poppins';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check the url.

example:

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,100&display=swap');